# Java: how to print an entire array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I'm trying to print an array of seven strings, and am using a get method to return them to the min before printing, but whenever I run it some random gibberish shows up on the console: [Ljava.lang.String;@6d6de4e1

Here is my get method

```
String[] getStuff(){
    return stuff;
}
```

And here is the print method from the main class:

```
System.out.println(trex.getStuff());
```

The array is completely valid and full of Strings, so I'm not sure what this error is.

Comment: Try to convert this array to list and then print the list using method toString(). Use Arrays.asList(trex.getStuff()) for conversion

Comment: You're printing the object, you need to loop through the array and print each object individually.

Comment: @TomaszBekas why bother converting to a List... just print with `Arrays.toString()` or `Arrays.deepToString()`

Comment: @Java Devil Oh yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You want to print the string values of the interior objects, not the string value of the array. Luckily java has a builtin for this: Arrays.deepToString()

So your print code should be:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(trex.getStuff()));
```

Comment: I don't know if you want commas. I think `Arrays.deepToString()` adds ", " for each element. This may/may not be desirable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out a reference to the seven strings and not not the 7 strings.
To print out the String either use a for loop

```
for (String str : array) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

or use the static Array method `Arrays.toString(array);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) static helper method as follows:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(trex.getStuff()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make use of the `Arrays.toString(String[])`. Import java.util.Arrays;

Otherwise, you can iterate over the returned array. 
What you're seeing is the address of memory where the array starts, rather than its elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to print a `list`.

Instead, try iterating over each `element` in the list via a `for` loop.

```
for(String str : trex.getStuff()) System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a for loop and print out each item in the array. For example:

```
String[] arr = trex.getStuff();
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```